# To create a class called Calculator which contains methods for arithmetic operations

Tags: c#

The question is 
Create a class called Calculator which contains methods for arithmetic operations such as Addition, Subtraction ,Multiplication and Division. Division method should return the Quotient and Remainder(hint:use out parameter).

Follow the method signatures as given below:

public int Addition(int a, int b)

public int Subtraction(int a, int b)

public int Multiplication(int a, int b)

public double Division(int a, int b, out double remainder).  //The method should  return the Quotient and Remainder  should be  passed through the out parameter.

The methods should return the appropriate result.

Create a class Program with Main Method . Prompt for 2 operands and operator from the user, Call the appropriate method for operation and display the results.

Note:

Don't create any new namespace.

Create classes with pubic access specifier

Sample Input

Enter the operator

+

Enter the operands

12

10

Sample Output

Result of 12 + 10 is 22

Sample Input

Enter the operator

/

Enter the operands

11

2

Sample Output

Result of 11 / 2 is 5

Remainder =1

Sample Input

Enter the operator

&

Enter the operands

12

10

Sample Output

Invalid Operator

My code is:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the operator");
        string sign = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the operands");
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Calculator cal = new Calculator();
        switch (sign)
        {
            case "+":
                Console.WriteLine("Result of " + a + " + " + b + " is " + cal.Addition(a,b));
                break;
            case "-":
                Console.WriteLine("Result of " + a + " - " + b + " is " + cal.Subtraction(a,b));
                break;
            case "*":
                Console.WriteLine("Result of " + a + " * " + b + " is " + cal.Multiplication(a,b));
                break;
            case "/":
                double[] ans = cal.Division(a,b, out remainder);
                Console.WriteLine("Result of " + a + " / " + b + " is " + ans[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("Remainder =" + (int)ans[1]);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
                break;
        }
    }

}
internal class Calculator
{
    public virtual int Addition(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    public virtual int Subtraction(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
    public virtual int Multiplication(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
    public virtual double[] Division(int a, int b,out double remainder)
    {
        return new double[]{a / b, a % b};
    }
}
```

Error:

Proposed grade: 0 / 100
Result Description
 COMPILE TIME ERROR``
Comment :=>> CalculatorProgram.cs(25,42): error CS0103: The name `remainder' does not exist in the current context
CalculatorProgram.cs(50,59): error CS0177: The out parameter`remainder' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method
Grade :=>> 0

Comment: Use this: `cal.Division(a,b, out var remainder);`. Since C#6 we can do this inline, before we had to declare the variable before the call to the function like so: `int remainder; cal.Division(a, b, out remainder);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
public virtual double[] Division(int a, int b,out double remainder)
```

Lets see what this signature tells us:

1. Its called `Division` so it will probably divide two numbers. What type of division is not altogether clear.
2. Integer arguments `a` and `b` are *probably* the numbers used in the division. But its not clear which is the *dividend* and which is the *divisor*. `a` is *probably* the former and `b` is *probably* the later. RULE: if there are a lot of *probably's* in the way to use a given method, then something is not right. Consider naming `a` and `b` to something that identifies them clearly.
3. The method accepts a `double` variable passed by reference `remainder` that *must* be set before the method `Division` returns (that's what `out` means). The value is the remainder of the division operation. But wait, the remainder of the division of two integers is always an integer, why declare it as a `double`?
4. The method returns a `double` array. Ok, that doesn't make much sense. The division of two numbers is a number, so this method should return a `double`, not an array of doubles. But wait... that doesn't make sense either. If you are returning through the `out` parameter the *remainder* of the division of two natural numbers, then we are performing an [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) and therefore the returned value should be the *quotient* of the division.
5. The method is marked as virtual. There is no apparent reason why this method sould be virtual so don't declare it as such. Always remember; making a non virtual method later on virtual is much easier than making a virtual method later on non virtual.

With all that, our signature would look like:

```
 public int EuclideanDivision(int dividend, int divisor, out int remainder)
```

And the implementation is straighforward:

```
remainder = .... //remember, the out argument must be initialized before the method returns!
var quotient = ....
return quotient;
```

That said, it seems the problem states you should use the following signature, which doesn't change the solution:

```
public double EuclideanDivision(int dividend, int divisor, out double remainder)
```

You can probably earn extra points in your homework pointing out that this signature is improvable.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the operator");
        string sign = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the operands");
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Calculator cal = new Calculator();
        switch (sign)
        {
            case "+":
                Console.WriteLine("Result of " + a + " + " + b + " is " + cal.Addition(a,b));
                break;
            case "-":
                Console.WriteLine("Result of " + a + " - " + b + " is " + cal.Subtraction(a,b));
                break;
            case "*":
                Console.WriteLine("Result of " + a + " * " + b + " is " + cal.Multiplication(a,b));
                break;
            case "/":
               double div = cal.Division(a, b,out double remainder);
                Console.WriteLine("Result of {0} / {1} is {2} \nRemainder = {3} ",a,b,div,remainder);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
                break;
        }
    }

}
internal class Calculator
{
    public virtual int Addition(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    public virtual int Subtraction(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
    public virtual int Multiplication(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
    
    public virtual double Division(int a,int b,out double remainder)
        {
            double div = a / b;
            double rem = a % b;
            remainder = rem;
            return div;
        }
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).